# Cypher query to get path between distant nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am pretty new to neo4j/cypher and i need your help with a query.

With this cypher statement: `Match p=(a:Value_Node {katalog_name:"id"})-[r:RELATED_TO_*]->(b:Value_Node {katalog_name:"Gewicht"}) return p` i get that picture below.

But i want to query only the path for one `value` that is also given in the properties (`id_nr`) of the relation `RELATED_TO_`. So i am looking for the path of one id from Start-node `(a:Value_Node {katalog_name:"id"})` to End-Node `(b:Value_Node {katalog_name:"Gewicht"}`.
With this query: `Match p=(a:Value_Node {katalog_name:"id"})-[r:RELATED_TO_*]->(b:Value_Node {katalog_name:"Gewicht"}) WHERE (a.value = r.id_nr) return p` i get the Errormessage:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
> Type mismatch: expected Map, Node, Relationship, Point, Duration, Date, Time, LocalTime, LocalDateTime or DateTime but was List (line 1, column 117 (offset: 116))
> "Match p=(a:Value_Node {katalog_name:"id"})-[r:RELATED_TO_*]->(b:Value_Node {katalog_name:"Gewicht"}) WHERE (a.value=r.id_nr) return p"
> `

[image]

Any help is useful!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look for all relationships of any length (r:RELATED_TO_*) the value of r is a list of all relationship from value_node named "id" to value_node name "Gewicht". Thus you should iterate on this list and check if the value of a.value is equal to ALL items in r.

```
Match p=(a:Value_Node {katalog_name:"id"})-[r:RELATED_TO_*]->(b:Value_Node {katalog_name:"Gewicht"}) 
WHERE ALL(rel in r WHERE rel.id_nr = a.value)
return p
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! Where can I look up such pieces of information about the return type of such statements or functions? Oh, I see it is written in the error message. But is there another source?

Comment: Yes, you can inspect the data type by RETURN r OR you can use an apoc function.